# NHibernate: Custom Dialect - how to specify the class in a separate assembly

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

I have a project which uses NHibernate and I have a custom dialect:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

    public class NHibernateMySQL5InnoDBDialect : NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    {
        public override String TableTypeString { get { return " ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"; } }
    }
```

I have a separate assembly for this class: Assembly1. Assembly1 is built into the directory where NHibernate.dll is.

In my cfg file I added:

```
<property name="dialect">Assembly1.NHibernateMySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
```

When I run my app I get the following error:

`NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: XXX.hbm.xml ---> NHibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate dialect class Assembly1.NHibernateMySQL5InnoDBDialect ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type Assembly1.NHibernateMySQL5InnoDBDialect. Possible cause: no assembly name specified.
  at NHibernate.Util.ReflectHelper.TypeFromAssembly (NHibernate.Util.AssemblyQualifiedTypeName name, Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in :0`

I'm sure there is an obvious explanation for this but I'm stuck at the moment - could you help?

Regards
Tymek

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<property name="dialect">MyAssembly1.MyDialectClass1, MyAssembly1</property>
```

Comment: <property name="dialect">MyDialectClass1, MyAssembly1</property> 

worked for me. BTW. How did you know about this?

Comment: @Tymek I had to add MSSQL full text search function to NHibernate in my last project, so I developed custom Dialect. So I knew the syntax of configuration. Look at error message: 'Possible cause: no assembly name specified.' :)

Comment: I dig what the message says: 'Possible cause: no assembly name specified.' - how did you know that you have to specify it with comma,name :)

Comment: @Tymek this is common syntax in all .net configuration: Namespace.ClassName, AssemblyName